# How to set tax amount to zero on Checkout page refresh

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, shipping-tax

When I go to checkout page after adding some product in my cart and then fill billing and shipping form then Total table shows me shipping tax based on shipping address.

But when I reload or refresh the checkout page the info of billinng and shipping form has gone but tax amount (calculated before refreshing the page) is still showing in Total review table.  I want to set it to zero. I have applied below code but did not work-

```
$shippingaddress = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$shippingaddress->setTaxAmount(0);
$shippingaddress->save();
```

this code set tax Amount to '0.00' in review table on page loading for a while but when page is fully loaded then this tax amount is replaced by old tax amount. But I want it to remain '0.00'. How I can do that.?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of shipping tax class from getShippingTaxClass() located into config.php located at app/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Config.php.

Remember that you need to override this file into your local pool.